# Trying to automate deployment with Azure Pipelines but warning due to not using Windows?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops

I'm trying to use Azure Pipelines for the first time and have finally managed to configure my azure-pipelines.yml file so it runs tests and should automatically deploy if the tests pass. However, I'm receiving this error:

[image]

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: ThermostatTestProject'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <mySubscription>
    WebAppName: <myWebAppName>
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip'

- task: PublishSymbols@2
  displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
  inputs:
    SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
    PublishSymbols: false
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I'm using a Mac - does anyone know how I can edit the yml file to make sure that it's Mac compatible and to get rid of this warning? I've been searching all day and cannot find a solution :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to automate deployment with Azure Pipelines but warning due to not using Windows?

That because the task [Index Sources & Publish Symbols task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) **was written for Windows only** not for Linux. When you execute this build pipeline on the agent `ubuntu-latest`, you will get that error.

So, this issue is not about Mac compatible but that task not compatible with Linux.

For this issue, MS replied:

> Currently we don't support publishing symbols from a Linux machine.
>   What you could do is use SourceLink to index as usual as part of your
>   build and then have a job that runs on Windows to publish the symbols.
>   When we look at support *.snupkg packaging we will look to address the
>   Linux symbol publishing scenario.

Ticket here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/3041

Besides, if you do not need to publish symbols from a Linux machine, you can disable this task.

Hope this helps.